# modernizr duplicates scripts when resizing screen

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries, modernizr

i'm placing scripts with modernizr for specyfic screen widths. Everything works fine for initial load but when I change tablet orientation from portrait to landscape there are two problems: scritps wpn't be loaded at all or modernizr will duplicate them every time i will switch to given orientation. See the code I'm using:

```
        Modernizr.load([
            {
                test : Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 600px)'),
                yep : ['/js/supersized/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js','/js/supersized/css/supersized.core.css'],
                complete : function() {
                    if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width:600px)')) {
                        jQuery(function($){
                            $.supersized({
                                fit_portrait: true,
                                slides  : [
                                    {image : img/sample.jpg', title : 'sample'}
                                ]
                            });
                        }); 
                    };
                }
            }
        ]);
```

so when changing orientation from below 600px to bigger one (after loading in narrower version) it doesn't load the script.
But when I add $(window).bind('resize', function(){   it keeps adding scripts and css to head ( so i got like a lot of scripts of supersized attached to head).

So basically the question is: is there any chance for modernizr to check on window resize if the script has ben alerady once included or is there a posibility to remove script from head when resizing below specified breakpoint (in my case 600px).

Arek

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've only tested in FF and Chrome and it is annoying. I havn't found a solution to this yet, but if I do, I'll come back and update this.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was creating a loaded var and set it to false outside of a function that runs mondernizr.load. In the same function I set loaded = true. I then call this function on load and on resize. Here is an example of how you can do this with your code.

```
var loaded = false;

// Set up function to call when DOM is ready and on resize
var loadScripts = function(){

    // Check to make sure our code has not run yet
    if(!loaded){

        Modernizr.load([{
            test : Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 600px)'),
            yep : ['/js/supersized/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js','/js/supersized/css/supersized.core.css'],
           complete : function() {
               if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width:600px)')) {
                   jQuery(function($){
                       $.supersized({
                           fit_portrait: true,
                           slides  : [{image : 'img/sample.jpg', title : 'sample'}]
                        });
                    }); 
                }
            } 
        }]);

       // Switch loaded over to true so Modernizr.load is not run again on resize
       loaded = true;

    } // End if!loaded

};

// Run when DOM is ready
loadScripts();

// Run on resize
if( window.addEventListener ){
    window.addEventListener( "resize", loadScripts, false );
}
```

Comment: sounds like a good resolution to that. I have to try it and will let you know if it works for me. Thank you.